# Moment with Timezone not properly formatting date

Tags: momentjs

I'm attempting to format `2014-10-03T23:09:42.764Z` using Moment with Timezones so that I can properly display it for the app's users. However, no matter what timezone I input into Moment it still keeps displaying the current locale's timezone: (I'm in EST)

```
moment('2014-10-03T23:09:42.764Z').tz('Europe/Paris').format()
"2014-10-03T19:09:42-04:00"
moment('2014-10-03T23:09:42.764Z').tz('Europe/London').format()
"2014-10-03T19:09:42-04:00"
```

Even though I input both London and Paris, it still displays it in my current timezone. Is there a way to force Moment to display in the given timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct, and it works when testing in the Chrome dev tools debugger console while on the moment-timezone website:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var a = moment('2014-10-03T23:09:42.764Z').tz('Europe/Paris').format();
var b = moment('2014-10-03T23:09:42.764Z').tz('Europe/London').format();

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b;
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

I can only conclude that you have not loaded the moment-timezone data correctly.

Comment: That was it! I didn't realize (and saw after reading more thoroughly) that I needed to include the `moment-timezone-with-data` instead of just `moment-timezone` files. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like :

```
var m = moment.tz('2014-10-03T23:09:42.764Z', 'America/Toronto');    
m.tz("Europe/Paris").format();
```

to set the default timezone, in your post:

```
var date = moment('2014-10-03T23:09:42.764Z')
```

it seems, there is no default time zone information in the date object.

You can see the official [documentation](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) to have more detail.

I hope it may help

Comment: The timestamp already has a timezone, I'm looking to display it in a different timezone by name.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i edited my post to take care of your comment.

Comment: There is a difference between `moment.tz(timestamp,timezone)` and `moment.tz(timezone)`.  The first parses the original moment with respect to the supplied time zone, and is used when a timestamp does not contain an offset.  The second is used to *convert* an existing timestamp to the specified time zone.  Since the original timestamp already contains a `Z`, it is already parsed as UTC.  The OP's code is correct.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I don't know this thing: I tried to help, and at end you help me more. i voted up

Comment: Could you please cp your comment in your post, it is really important for josh issue. I will delete my post as it is not relevant.